# for loop performs first action but not the second

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a for loop that I want to:

**1)** Make a pivot table out of the data

**2)** Convert the 5min data to 30min data

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os 
import glob 


os.chdir('C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test')

for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test'):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=[0])
    table = pd.pivot_table(data, values='SCADAVALUE',columns=['DUID'],index='SETTLEMENTDATE', aggfunc=np.sum)
    table.to_csv(filename+'pivoted.csv')


my_csv_files = []
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test"):
    if file.endswith("*pivoted.csv"):
        table.set_index(table.columns[0])
        table.index = pd.to_datetime(table.index) 
        table_resampled = table.resample('30min',closed='right',label='right').mean() 
        table_resampled = table_resampled.reset_index() 
        table.to_csv(filename+'30min.csv')
```

The code performs the first loop, but the second loop does not work.Why is this? Whats wrong with my code?

EDIT1:

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why my second loop fails?

Comment: "does not work"... how? Wrong result? Error? Not executed?...

Comment: Do you have file that ends with "*pivoted.csv" ?

Comment: while there is no error, but it doesn't output any fiiles

Comment: yes I have the pivoted files

Comment: I'll show you the ouput

Comment: why are you using * there? Is that to mention all as in linux, if so that might be one reason because your file doesnot start with *.

Comment: I'm using it beause I have a lot of different files, but I want to perform the tasks only on the ones that end in pivoted. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think no, I suggest to make a list of files that you want to read for some task.

Comment: It also reads files already pivoted. So the second time it runs, it tries to pivot something already pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

See comment below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os 
import glob 


os.chdir('C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test')

for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test'):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=[0])
    table = pd.pivot_table(data, values='SCADAVALUE',columns=['DUID'],index='SETTLEMENTDATE', aggfunc=np.sum)
    table.to_csv(filename+'pivoted.csv')


my_csv_files = []  # what is this variable for?
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/george/Desktop/testing/output/test"):
    if file.endswith("*pivoted.csv"):

        # At this point you are not reading the file, but you should.  
        # The 'table' variable is still making reference to the the last iteration
        # of the 'for' loop a few lines above

        # However, better than re-reading the file, you can remove 
        # the second 'for file in...' loop,
        # and just merge the code with the first loop

        table.set_index(table.columns[0])
        table.index = pd.to_datetime(table.index) 
        table_resampled = table.resample('30min',closed='right',label='right').mean() 
        table_resampled = table_resampled.reset_index() 
        table.to_csv(filename+'30min.csv')
```